# push ELEMENTS of array to an array using Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, push

using Perl I am trying to push the elements of an array to another array, and not the whole array. But I'm not getting my goal.

I tried this:

```
push @tmp_entities_all, @tmp_entities;
```

But I got the whole small array as an element in the bigger array.

Then I tried it with a loop:

```
for (@tmp_entities) {push @tmp_entities_all, $_;}
```

But the same results, the whole `@tmp_entities` appears as an element, and that what I dont want.

I need one dimension in the array and not array of arrays!! Should I cast something before pushing? or what is the problem?

Thanx a lot.

Comment: Both methods should work. Try to dump your `@tmp_entities_all` after `push` by `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\@tmp_entities_all);` and include the output in your question.

Comment: [
            {
              'type' => 'month',
              'attr' => {
                        }
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              'type' => 'day',
              'attr' => {
                        }
            },
            {
              'type' => 'day',
              'attr' => {
                        }
            }
          ],...

Comment: try this oneliner ``perl -e '@a=(1,2,3,4); @b=(5,6,7,8); push @a,@b; print "@a\n";'`` as you can see what you are asking should work

Comment: The loop is working now: I've changed it to @$_ instead of simply $_.. But the other method is more effective and should somehow work..

Comment: Your array @tmp_entities contains an arrayreference, that is holding the elements. Perhaps you defined your array like that **@tmp_entities = [ 1, 2, 3]** ... but you should do **@tmp_entities = ( 1, 2, 3 )** ...  This is, why your loop works with @$_ and your push in the first try push the arrays "as one element" ...

Comment: @abounnour You simplified your problem wrongly in your original post, for example, it looks like your `@tmp_entities_all` is an array of list reference of hash references. Please use the actually data structure in your question.

Comment: hmmm ur example worked as wanted.. May be I'm initializins my array wrong.. I've created @tmp_entities like this:
$doc->entities->{$key};
where entities is a hash and $key points to an array.. That array is my goal to catch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of your comments, its obvious, that `@tmp_entities` contains only one element, that is an array reference to the elements that you expected to be elements of `@tmp_entities`.

So you perhaps declared your array with an array refence instead of using a set of elements.

The line

```
push @tmp_entities_all, @tmp_entities;
```

definitly works for a normal array.

In your case, your could try ...

```
push @tmp_entities_all, $tmp_entities[0];
```

or you simply try to initialize your array with its value like

```
my @tmp_entities = ( 1, 2, 3 ); # initialize array with 3 elements of type int
```

instead of

```
my @tmp_entities = [ 1, 2, 3 ]; # initialize array with 1 element that is an array reference with 3 elements of type int
```

I know, that this is the case, because this is why your for-loop sample works with `@$_` ;D (it is equivalent to `push @tmp_entities_all, $tmp_entities[0];` in this situation).

Comment: another way could be to use: `my @tmp_entities = qw/1 2 3/;`.